# How do these holes form?

Tags: geology, rocks, islands, pacific

I was casually browsing the google earth street view map today. And I noticed strange cavities in a rock wall on Henderson Island, a coral island in the South Pacific. What could have caused this to form?

[link](https://earth.app.goo.gl/?apn=com.google.earth&isi=293622097&ius=googleearth&link=https%3A%2F%2Fearth.google.com%2Fweb%2F%40-24.34041526,-128.3284743,28.870924a,0d,90y,119.85663851h,103.66404756t,0r%2Fdata%3DIhoKFlJJMzBsVUVOSnFraUpOS2xsUmUzVmcQAjoDCgEw)
[image]

Comment: look up chemical weathering.

Answer (score 0):

These are calcite-based rock layers and the reaction between these and H2CO3 (CO2 +H2O) causes the calcite to erode.

Consequently, the reaction:

H2O +CO2 -> H2CO3

H2CO3 +CaCO3 <-> Ca + 2 HCO3

This reactin is mainly found in slightly acidic environments.